# Is there a rest api endpoint for JWT Authentication through Docusign?

Tags: docusignapi

I have gotten JWT Authentication via DocuSign working with their Docusign.Esign.dll, but a project I am working on may not be able to use said dll. Is there a rest API endpoint equivalent for JWT authentication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, there is, [documentation by following](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/oauth2-jsonwebtoken)

You make the call to `https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token`
with body that looks like this (not real values):

```
{
  "iss": "7c2b8d7e-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-cda8a50dd73f",
  "sub": "664f7988-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-781ee556ab7a",
  "iat": 1523900289,
  "exp": 1523903289,
  "aud": "account-d.docusign.com",
  "scope": "signature impersonation"
}
```

Comment: does docusign require a specific content type for these requests?

Comment: I don't think so. it's pure JSON. If you run into issues - let me know

Comment: The body is a JWT that includes the claims shown in this answer. The JWT is signed by a key you download from the eSignature admin tool.

Comment: Sorry if this is a dumb question, but what do I do with the respone from this call that help me acquire a token I can use for other docusign rest api calls?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can perform JWT authentication without the library. The process to do so is documented here: https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/oauth2-jsonwebtoken

In short, once you have granted consent, you make a POST call against a specific endpoint on the account server:

```
curl --data "grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer&assertion=eyJhbGciO.....00V-pTPzg"
--request POST https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token
```